# Why doesn't my program approximate pi?

Tags: python, random, pi

For yesterday's Pi Day, Matt Harper published a video in which he approximated Pi by rolling two 120-sided dice 500 times ([see the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZBhSi_PwHU&t=139s)). Basically, for each pair of random numbers, you have to check whether they are coprime or not. Then, the formula

```
pi = sqrt(6/(n_coprimes/n_cofactors))   # EDIT: Wrong premise. Misremembered the formula.
```

is calculated.

His result was about 3.05 which is rather close.

I wanted to see what happens when more rolls are done or when the range of random integers is increased. Interestingly, my program nearly always gave a result of 3.05 or close to it, no matter how high I set the iterations or the random range.

Here is my program. I ran it on Python 3.6 (Win64). The random number generator Python uses is supposed to be very good, so maybe I've made a mistake in my program?

```
import random
from math import gcd, sqrt

def pi(cp, cf):
    return sqrt(6/(cf/cp))    # EDIT: Second error - switched numerator/denominator...

coprime = 0
cofactor = 0

iterations = 1000000

for i in range(iterations):
    x = random.randint(0,1000000)
    y = random.randint(0,1000000)
    if gcd(x,y) > 1: 
        cofactor += 1
    else:
        coprime += 1

print(pi(coprime, cofactor))
```

Comment: Saw the video yesterday and didn't even think to try this myself. Thanks for the idea! As for why it doesn't gain accuracy, idk. My best guess would be a limitation of the generator, but I know little about Python's generator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't watched the video, but your formula is wrong.

The probability that two ints picked randomly from 1 to N are coprime tends to 6/pi^2 as N tends to infinity. That's cp/(cf + cp) and not cp/cf.

Replacing your `pi` with this:

```
def pi(cp, cf):
    fcp = cp / float(cp + cf)
    return sqrt(6/fcp)
```

Gives 3.14263472915 when I run it on my machine.

Comment: @Random832: That's because there's another error. It should be `6/(cp/total)`, not `6/(cf/cp)` or `6/(cf/total)`.

Comment: Could you cite a reference for your final formula? I'm looking up formal derivations, but they all employ measure theory and I'm unable to connect that back to coprimes and cofactors.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan it's simple algebra to derive it from the original assertion that P=6/pi^2. All the complex stuff going to be in proving that assertion rather than transforming it into how to approximate pi.

Comment: D'oh! I'm sure that I misremembered the formula. Ouch. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probabilities shows the derivation up to the infinite sum. Showing the infinite sum is pi^2/6 is somewhat harder, and IIRC you use the power series of atan or similar, evaluated at some value. That's vague, but hopefully can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, wikipedia provides a link to the bit I was vague about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: The video seems to be using the correct formula; it's just a coincidence that the video's result was so close to the value the incorrect formula produces.

Comment: @PaulHankin Op specified python 3.6 so `float` is extraneous. (parenthesis are needed tho)

Comment: A smaller error in your program is that your random ranges should start from 1, not 0. That adds an error that asymptotically tends to zero, but isn't zero.

Comment: @Aaron sure, I included it because that's the version I ran on my own computer, which doesn't have py3.6.

Comment: I first had the range from 1 to x; when it didn't provide the desired result, I tried it with 0. No luck (for obvious reasons). Now, with the correct formula, I got 3.141567 on the first try.